# How can I persist NERDTree settings?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'd like to persist some NERDtree settings, such as make all the hidden files visible so that I don't have to press 'I' each time I open it. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Most good vim plugins always have really good documentation.  If you hate reading man pages, you hate reading man pages, but if a vim plugin is good, that likely means it does one thing and its documentation should be pretty short.  In the case of NERDtree it's a little long, but even skimming `:h NERDTreeOptions` should result in a few "Oh!  I can do THAT!?" moments.

Comment: I don't hate reading it. I just didn't realize that. I've searched through the homepage and couldn't find it, that's why I seek help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:h nerdtreeshowhidden`

Setting `let NERDTreeShowHidden=1` in your .vimrc will accomplish this.